# nginx: how do i cancle a request with "No Response", like "return 444" via fcgi?

Tags: nginx

i like to block out some bot trying to do bad stuff to my web-applications.
a daily cronjobs extends my block.conf, containing a lof of `deny a.b.c.d` lines.
before the cronjob runs at 4am and after some host ir recognized as bad i look them up in the database and stop processing and response with an empty http-body, but i like to be able to to response with an empty response as well here, like i do with the one that matches de rules from the block.conf.

is there any way to do it? like sending a header or anything?
thanks

Comment: There is similar question http://serverfault.com/questions/403425/nginx-return-444-depending-on-upstream-response-code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at [naxsi](https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi) which is a Web Application Firewall Module for nginx that you can configure using your own rules to exactly catch certain bot scanning patterns.

Additionaly you could install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and configure it to work with naxsi and automatically banning certain patterns. https://code.google.com/p/naxsi/wiki/NaxsiFail2ban

The good thing is that fail2ban blocks hosts on network/iptabels level instead of just denying request by the webserver. So it's more restrictive and eventually more secure as the bad ips can't access your webserver anymore at all.

Comment: sadly fail2ban isn't an option since my application runs inside vserver and docker containers so iptables is none of the bussiness we can deal with. - iam pretty fine with the block ing setup where nginx blocks the bad guys, bots searching for unsecured guestbook-forms are not a security-problem for me, just a performance-problem.

Comment: You still might want to look at naxsi if you have the chance to use it. Even without fail2ban/iptables it's only server side blocking then but gives you way more possibilities due to the rules you can use.